# Redirecting to another page not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

Hi folks.  In my MVC application, I am trying to redirect to a login page, however it is not redirecting and I am getting a "server error".

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function keepAlive() { 
window.clearTimeout(window.sessionKeepAlive); 
window.sessionKeepAlive = window.setTimeout(function() { 

    if(confirm('refresh session?')) { 
        // submit coding required 
    } else { 
        //window.location="/Employee/~/Account/LogOn"
        //location.replace("/Employee/~/Account/LogOn");
        window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action( "Logout", "Account" ) %>'; 
    } 

}, <%= (Session.Timeout - 19) * 60 * 1000 %>); 
} 
keepAlive(); 
</script>
```

Also, I need the code for if the user presses the 'ok' button and it continues.

Comment: You are getting a server error, really, no kidding? Let's play a game: the first one who guesses the server error wins a free beer. Also your last sentence is difficult to follow.

Comment: May be you are getting error after redirection

Comment: when i click the cancel button it sholud go to the login page but its not going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I prefer to add the full path link to web.config in

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="BaseURL" value="http://localhost/" />
</appSettings>
```

And declare an application variable in Global.asax in

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Application["BaseURL"] = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
}
```

And now I can use the variables in the whole site. In you case, you can simply use by

```
window.location.href = '<%=Application["BaseURL"]%>account/logout';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the location you're redirecting to includes the protocol i.e.

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.yoursite.tld/account/logout';
```

For the second bit you can make an ajax call to a heartbeat page to refresh the session

```
// simplified
try {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch( e ) {
    var xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

xhr.open( 'get', 'http://heartbeat/url', true );
xhr.send( null );
```

Comment: i am running in local how to provide the link 'http://www.yoursite.tld/account/logout'

Comment: I think you can just modify the pathname instead  

`window.location.pathname = '/account/logout'`