# EveryOne Min Script is called

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

In my MVC application, when I run my application when I didn't do any changes in my application the scripts work and goes to the to login page after one min (to test the script I have default set `-1` to the `sessiontimeout` so it will be easy to check script working or not) , now my issue is when I contionusly go on working in my appication also it's redirecting to login page do how to modify this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function keepAlive() {  
    window.clearTimeout(window.sessionKeepAlive);  
    window.sessionKeepAlive = window.setTimeout( function() {  
        window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action( "LogOn", "Account" ) %>'; 
    }, <%= (Session.Timeout - 19) * 60 * 1000 %>);  
} keepAlive();

</script>
```

Comment: wasn't this asked a wee while ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406776/redirecting-to-another-page-not-working-in-javascript - puzzled of penzance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the typical (default) session timeout is 20 minutes, and you're subtracting 19...I think you want to just subtract `1` here so you get 60 seconds notice, so this:

```
<%= (Session.Timeout - 19) * 60 * 1000 %>
```

Should be:

```
<%= (Session.Timeout - 1) * 60 * 1000 %>
```

Comment: for test case i have given -19 i when i contiously work also i should not get refreshed

Comment: @Karthik - I don't understand the question then, it sounded like the issue was the frequency, what do you *want* to happen that's not happening now?

Comment: see craver when i run my application when i didnt do any changes in my application the scripts work and goes to the  to login page after one min, now my issue is when i contionusly go on working in my appication also its redirecting to login page do get my point?